# how to add ' like special characters in mysql varchar data type column?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am trying to insert string as "baby's world" into the column of type varchar through query but shows me error.
Is there anything else i need to put to the query so that it accept that symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put a backslash in front of it like so:

```
"Baby\'s world"
```

You can find and replace them in your string using the following:

```
str.Replace('\'', '\\\'')
```

I'm not 100% sure about this last part, but you need to 'escape' the ' and \ by adding a \ in front of it. So it would seem alright (can't test as i'm not a C# programmer.

Comment: What do you mean with "how can i work with query?"? If you add a \ in front of every ' inside of the string there is no problem.

Comment: i ment i am inserting data through query so as the value passed in textbox and textbox value is going in insert query then how can i detect that any special symbol is going or not

Comment: In php there is a function named addslashes which does the work for you. You could Google an equivalent in your chosen language.

Comment: Becouse you are using c# i added it in the answer. Good luck, let me know if it works :) There is no 'addslashes()' function for .NET according to Microsoft.

Comment: You could try this. I'm not a c# programmer either: http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-AddSlashes-StripSlashes-Escape-String.html

Comment: If it's only the ' you worry about the solution i gave you should work, if you want to catch all possible problems this link Hadleigh gave should be usefull, i found it too some time ago.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking about Visual Studio (.NET), you need to use parameterized query. Don't use concatenation when constructing query

```
private void PrepareExample()
{
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO movie(title) VALUES (?title)", myConnection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "?title", "baby's world" );
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Or

```
private void PrepareExample()
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO movie(title) VALUES (?title)", myConnection);
    // try to input: baby's world. or try: baby"s world. everything are ok :-)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "?title", Console.ReadLine() ); 
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Though this is not exactly concatenation, don't use this:

```
qry = string.Format("INSERT INTO movie(title) VALUES("{0}", Console.ReadLine());
```

Though if you really found a need to run SQL that way, replace single quote with backslash

```
qry = string.Format("INSERT INTO movie(title) VALUES("{0}", 
              Console.ReadLine().Replace("'", "\'");
```

But do consider using parameterized query instead of concatenation or string.Format, as parameterized query automatically take care of those delimeter nuances.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use `mysql_real_escape_string()`. There is no need to do anything else.

For example:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($user),
mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('baby's world')` will fail because the string is truncated to `INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('baby'` and the rest is seen as invalid code.

There are two ways to stop this, the second being advisable for good practice coding:

`INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ("baby's world")`

`INSERT INTO table (field) VAUES ('baby\'s world')`

Comment: true.that is working fine. but what in case of `INSERT INTO table (field) values ('+name.txt+')`  ?  where name.txt is having text as "baby's world"